# Sign in with Apple - Hide email

Tags: ios, single-sign-on

On 'Sign in with Apple' If the user opted for “Hide my Email”, he will be registered with a private email id. Again if the same user tries to Register with the original email address (with any social media account or with original email id), he will be treated as a different user?

How is it possible to make sure we have a unique user in the database after registration?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the email address as an unique identifier, you can use the "sub" parameter returned in the identity Token JWT, the value of this parameter is the same for the same Apple ID user and is unique, across all apps that belongs to your Apple developer account / organization.

Comment: Why can we not use the email address as a unique identifier? The documentation states that `a unique, random email address is created`

Comment: the `unique, random email address` is only created if user choose to hide their email address. The same user can come back to register again with their real Apple ID email address, this will make the users has two accounts.

If you use the "sub" parameter from the identity token JWT, it will be the same value regardless of user choose to hide/show their real email address

Comment: Oh, so you mean if they [Turn Off Email Forwarding](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT210426#turnoffemail), then the `jwt_payload.email` will change, but `jwt_payload.sub` will stay the same?

Comment: Correction: Regardless they choose to show or hide their email during the Sign in with Apple dialog (https://support.apple.com/en-my/HT210425), the jwt_payload.email will change, but jwt_payload.sub will stay the same.

Turning off email forwarding just means the user won't receive your email if they are using the randomly generated email by Apple

Comment: I thought that once a user is registered with a particular app using Apple Sign in, they will not be able to re-register for that app? And the same sub, email etc will be reused for subsequent Apple Sign in requests.

Comment: They can register (with real email), then go to iOS Settings app, revoke sign in for that app, and register again (with fake email Apple provides).
This will produce two different email, but the same sub.
Tried it with my own apps, it is a very edge case (unlikely user will do this), but it can happen

Answer (score 0):

As per apple doc: link (https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT210425)

> If you choose to hide your email when you create an account with an
>   app or website using Sign in with Apple, a unique, random email
>   address is created so your personal email can stay private.

To answer your question:

> If user sign-in with actual email id from another platform/social
>   login then this will be a new user for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they will be treated as a different user because the email is different (based on your auth business logic). The recommendation is to use [this user id](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20user%20identifier%20instead%20of%20an%20email%20address%20to%20identify%20the%20user.)

However I don't see many apps doing that, a lot of authentication systems just work out of the box with email auth, and require customizations to deal with this kind of deduplication across emails, especially when you consider other oauth providers (like google).

Also the hide my email has some handy [properties](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/communicating_using_the_private_email_relay_service/) which mean this relay email is stable (and the user can simply sign in with it again):

"Private relay email addresses have the following characteristics:

- They end in @privaterelay.appleid.com or @icloud.com.
- They route emails to one of the Apple ID’s verified email addresses.
- They’re the same for a user across all apps written by a single development team, and different for the same user across apps written by different development teams.
- They’re active whether or not the user is signed into a device, and whether or not your app is installed on the device. You may send and receive email to the private email address at any time.
  "

So whats the point of not using email? ROI vs effort here is lacking (at least in 2023).